# How to generate multiple prestashop discounts/coupons?

Tags: prestashop, coupon, discount, generate

I want to generate 100+ coupons for my prestashop 1.7 site, but i don't know how to to do it. Looks like there is now such possibility in backoffice.

Thanks for help)

Comment: Do you want to create 100+ different coupons or 100+ instances of the same coupon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lately I've used this module https://addons.prestashop.com/en/promotions-gifts/29454-discounts-coupons-manager-generate-and-import.html to generate 100+ instances of the same discount with unique code

It have generate and import options and looks nice